# How to add overflow-hidden in the image of this tailblock component?

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css, tailwind-ui

I am using the follwing tailblock component which is based on tailwind.css

What I want is when I hover, the image scales up within the image dimensions only. This means the image zooms but the dimension (height & width ) remains same.

I tried this, but it is overflowing the right side.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<section class="text-gray-600 body-font overflow-hidden">
  <div class="container px-5 py-24 mx-auto">
    <div class="lg:w-4/5 mx-auto flex flex-wrap overflow-hidden">
      <img alt="ecommerce" class="lg:w-1/2 w-full lg:h-auto h-64 object-cover object-center rounded transform transition duration-500 hover:scale-125 ease-in-out" src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400">
      <div class="lg:w-1/2 w-full lg:pl-10 lg:py-6 mt-6 lg:mt-0">
        <h2 class="text-sm title-font text-gray-500 tracking-widest">BRAND NAME</h2>
        <h1 class="text-gray-900 text-3xl title-font font-medium mb-1">The Catcher in the Rye</h1>
        
        <p class="leading-relaxed">Fam locavore kickstarter distillery. Mixtape chillwave tumeric sriracha taximy chia microdosing tilde DIY. XOXO fam indxgo juiceramps cornhole raw denim forage brooklyn. Everyday carry +1 seitan poutine tumeric. Gastropub blue bottle austin listicle pour-over, neutra jean shorts keytar banjo tattooed umami cardigan.</p>
        <div class="flex mt-6 items-center pb-5 border-b-2 border-gray-100 mb-5">
          <div class="flex">
            <span class="mr-3">Color</span>
            <button class="border-2 border-gray-300 rounded-full w-6 h-6 focus:outline-none"></button>
            <button class="border-2 border-gray-300 ml-1 bg-gray-700 rounded-full w-6 h-6 focus:outline-none"></button>
            <button class="border-2 border-gray-300 ml-1 bg-indigo-500 rounded-full w-6 h-6 focus:outline-none"></button>
          </div>
          <div class="flex ml-6 items-center">
            <span class="mr-3">Size</span>
            <div class="relative">
              <select class="rounded border appearance-none border-gray-300 py-2 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-indigo-200 focus:border-indigo-500 text-base pl-3 pr-10">
                <option>SM</option>
                <option>M</option>
                <option>L</option>
                <option>XL</option>
              </select>
              <span class="absolute right-0 top-0 h-full w-10 text-center text-gray-600 pointer-events-none flex items-center justify-center">
                <svg fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" class="w-4 h-4" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                  <path d="M6 9l6 6 6-6"></path>
                </svg>
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="flex">
          <span class="title-font font-medium text-2xl text-gray-900">$58.00</span>
          <button class="flex ml-auto text-white bg-indigo-500 border-0 py-2 px-6 focus:outline-none hover:bg-indigo-600 rounded">Button</button>
          <button class="rounded-full w-10 h-10 bg-gray-200 p-0 border-0 inline-flex items-center justify-center text-gray-500 ml-4">
            <svg fill="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" class="w-5 h-5" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
              <path d="M20.84 4.61a5.5 5.5 0 00-7.78 0L12 5.67l-1.06-1.06a5.5 5.5 0 00-7.78 7.78l1.06 1.06L12 21.23l7.78-7.78 1.06-1.06a5.5 5.5 0 000-7.78z"></path>
            </svg>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS `scale()` basically increases or decreases the size/dimensions of an element (according to actual width and height). If your actual image size is `100x100` and you're using `scale(1.1)` then the size will be `110x110`. So `overflow: hidden` won't hide the excessive parts.

In that case, just wrap the image with a `<div/>` element and apply `overflow: hidden` to it.

```
<div class="overflow-hidden">
  <img src="" alt=""/>
</div>
```

Here is the solved snippet:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<section class="text-gray-600 body-font overflow-hidden">
  <div class="container px-5 py-24 mx-auto">
    <div class="lg:w-4/5 mx-auto flex flex-wrap overflow-hidden">
      <div class="lg:w-1/2 w-full overflow-hidden">
        <img alt="ecommerce" class="w-full lg:h-auto h-64 object-cover object-center rounded transform transition duration-500 hover:scale-125 ease-in-out" src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400">
      </div>
      <div class="lg:w-1/2 w-full lg:pl-10 lg:py-6 mt-6 lg:mt-0">
        <h2 class="text-sm title-font text-gray-500 tracking-widest">BRAND NAME</h2>
        <h1 class="text-gray-900 text-3xl title-font font-medium mb-1">The Catcher in the Rye</h1>
        
        <p class="leading-relaxed">Fam locavore kickstarter distillery. Mixtape chillwave tumeric sriracha taximy chia microdosing tilde DIY. XOXO fam indxgo juiceramps cornhole raw denim forage brooklyn. Everyday carry +1 seitan poutine tumeric. Gastropub blue bottle austin listicle pour-over, neutra jean shorts keytar banjo tattooed umami cardigan.</p>
        <div class="flex mt-6 items-center pb-5 border-b-2 border-gray-100 mb-5">
          <div class="flex">
            <span class="mr-3">Color</span>
            <button class="border-2 border-gray-300 rounded-full w-6 h-6 focus:outline-none"></button>
            <button class="border-2 border-gray-300 ml-1 bg-gray-700 rounded-full w-6 h-6 focus:outline-none"></button>
            <button class="border-2 border-gray-300 ml-1 bg-indigo-500 rounded-full w-6 h-6 focus:outline-none"></button>
          </div>
          <div class="flex ml-6 items-center">
            <span class="mr-3">Size</span>
            <div class="relative">
              <select class="rounded border appearance-none border-gray-300 py-2 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-indigo-200 focus:border-indigo-500 text-base pl-3 pr-10">
                <option>SM</option>
                <option>M</option>
                <option>L</option>
                <option>XL</option>
              </select>
              <span class="absolute right-0 top-0 h-full w-10 text-center text-gray-600 pointer-events-none flex items-center justify-center">
                <svg fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" class="w-4 h-4" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                  <path d="M6 9l6 6 6-6"></path>
                </svg>
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="flex">
          <span class="title-font font-medium text-2xl text-gray-900">$58.00</span>
          <button class="flex ml-auto text-white bg-indigo-500 border-0 py-2 px-6 focus:outline-none hover:bg-indigo-600 rounded">Button</button>
          <button class="rounded-full w-10 h-10 bg-gray-200 p-0 border-0 inline-flex items-center justify-center text-gray-500 ml-4">
            <svg fill="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" class="w-5 h-5" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
              <path d="M20.84 4.61a5.5 5.5 0 00-7.78 0L12 5.67l-1.06-1.06a5.5 5.5 0 00-7.78 7.78l1.06 1.06L12 21.23l7.78-7.78 1.06-1.06a5.5 5.5 0 000-7.78z"></path>
            </svg>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could put the image in a `div` container and add the `overflow-hidden` class. Now the scaled image will never be bigger than its container.

##### Concept:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/2.2.19/tailwind.min.css" integrity="sha512-wnea99uKIC3TJF7v4eKk4Y+lMz2Mklv18+r4na2Gn1abDRPPOeef95xTzdwGD9e6zXJBteMIhZ1+68QC5byJZw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<div class="flex min-h-screen items-center justify-center p-10">
  <div class="h-24 w-full overflow-hidden rounded">
    <img class="h-full w-full transform object-cover object-center transition duration-500 ease-in-out hover:scale-125" src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400" />
  </div>
</div>
```

---

##### Original Code

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/2.2.19/tailwind.min.css" integrity="sha512-wnea99uKIC3TJF7v4eKk4Y+lMz2Mklv18+r4na2Gn1abDRPPOeef95xTzdwGD9e6zXJBteMIhZ1+68QC5byJZw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<section class="body-font overflow-hidden text-gray-600">
  <div class="container mx-auto px-5 py-24">
    <div class="mx-auto flex flex-wrap overflow-hidden lg:w-4/5">
      <!-- Image Container -->
      <div class="h-64 w-full overflow-hidden rounded lg:h-auto lg:w-1/2">
        <img alt="ecommerce" class="h-full w-full transform object-cover object-center transition duration-500 ease-in-out hover:scale-125" src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400" />
      </div>
      <!-- END Image Container -->
      <div class="mt-6 w-full lg:mt-0 lg:w-1/2 lg:py-6 lg:pl-10">
        <h2 class="title-font text-sm tracking-widest text-gray-500">BRAND NAME</h2>
        <h1 class="title-font mb-1 text-3xl font-medium text-gray-900">The Catcher in the Rye</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Hi but you are not putting all the content. If you put all the content , then `lg:w-1/2` will make image very thiner, and if you remove  `lg:w-1/2` then flex direction changes and items will appear up and down.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "putting all the content". Obviously, a significant part of the image will always be clipped when you try to fit a 1:1 image into a ~16:9 container. What do you want to happen at the `lg` breakpoint?

Comment: Basically I want to be both the items side by side. (putting all the content means including the text on the right side also)

Comment: This is what happens in the code I posted when the screen is > `lg`. https://play.tailwindcss.com/NP0m1xvjWj

Answer (score 1):

```
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<section class="text-gray-600 body-font overflow-hidden">
    <div class="container px-5 py-24 mx-auto">
        <div class="lg:w-4/5 mx-auto flex flex-wrap overflow-hidden">
            <div class="overflow-hidden w-full">
                <img alt="ecommerce"
                    class="w-full h-64 object-cover object-center rounded transform transition duration-500 hover:scale-125 ease-in-out"
                    src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400">
            </div>
            <div class="lg:w-1/2 w-full lg:pl-10 lg:py-6 mt-6 lg:mt-0">
                <h2 class="text-sm title-font text-gray-500 tracking-widest">BRAND NAME</h2>
                <h1 class="text-gray-900 text-3xl title-font font-medium mb-1">The Catcher in the Rye</h1>

                <p class="leading-relaxed">Fam locavore kickstarter distillery. Mixtape chillwave tumeric sriracha
                    taximy chia microdosing tilde DIY. XOXO fam indxgo juiceramps cornhole raw denim forage
                    brooklyn. Everyday carry +1 seitan poutine tumeric. Gastropub blue bottle austin listicle
                    pour-over, neutra jean shorts keytar banjo tattooed umami cardigan.</p>
                <div class="flex mt-6 items-center pb-5 border-b-2 border-gray-100 mb-5">
                    <div class="flex">
                        <span class="mr-3">Color</span>
                        <button class="border-2 border-gray-300 rounded-full w-6 h-6 focus:outline-none"></button>
                        <button
                            class="border-2 border-gray-300 ml-1 bg-gray-700 rounded-full w-6 h-6 focus:outline-none"></button>
                        <button
                            class="border-2 border-gray-300 ml-1 bg-indigo-500 rounded-full w-6 h-6 focus:outline-none"></button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="flex ml-6 items-center">
                        <span class="mr-3">Size</span>
                        <div class="relative">
                            <select
                                class="rounded border appearance-none border-gray-300 py-2 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-indigo-200 focus:border-indigo-500 text-base pl-3 pr-10">
                                <option>SM</option>
                                <option>M</option>
                                <option>L</option>
                                <option>XL</option>
                            </select>
                            <span
                                class="absolute right-0 top-0 h-full w-10 text-center text-gray-600 pointer-events-none flex items-center justify-center">
                                <svg fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round"
                                    stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" class="w-4 h-4" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                                    <path d="M6 9l6 6 6-6"></path>
                                </svg>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="flex">
                    <span class="title-font font-medium text-2xl text-gray-900">$58.00</span>
                    <button
                        class="flex ml-auto text-white bg-indigo-500 border-0 py-2 px-6 focus:outline-none hover:bg-indigo-600 rounded">Button</button>
                    <button
                        class="rounded-full w-10 h-10 bg-gray-200 p-0 border-0 inline-flex items-center justify-center text-gray-500 ml-4">
                        <svg fill="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2"
                            class="w-5 h-5" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                            <path
                                d="M20.84 4.61a5.5 5.5 0 00-7.78 0L12 5.67l-1.06-1.06a5.5 5.5 0 00-7.78 7.78l1.06 1.06L12 21.23l7.78-7.78 1.06-1.06a5.5 5.5 0 000-7.78z">
                            </path>
                        </svg>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

you have to put image into div and add class overflow-hidden and w-full or simply you can replce this code.

Comment: This is not working man because in your solution the flex direction is changing and items are displaying up and down and overflow is also not hidden

Comment: also you have to remove class from image  - lg:w-1/2, lg:h-auto 
Please try this code now.